# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError error when trying to compile using the new Groovy 3.0.4 compiler?

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a project using the new Groovy 3.0.4 compiler and Gradle 5.6.4:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.4"
    ...
```

But the compilation (`./gradlew  --stacktrace build`) fails with the error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

...

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/transform/stc/AbstractExtensionMethodCache
...
```

The class `AbstractExtensionMethodCache` is part of the Groovy compiler, why the compiler cannot find it? The project compiles fine with Groovy 2.5.12.

Comment: Is this with a fresh `gradle init` project with groovy and just the numbers
ramped up? Could you try from a minimal project and work your way up to the
problem?